# Typescript/React useRef Error: (property) React.RefObject<HTMLFormElement>.current: HTMLFormElement | null Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, typescript-typings

I'm having an issue with Typescript and it's giving me the following error listed below. The part of `const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);` seems to be good, but the issue looks to be with `formRef.current.checkValidity()`.

How can I add the Typescript typing/get rid of the error?

**Error:**

```
(property) React.RefObject<HTMLFormElement>.current: HTMLFormElement | null
Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)
```

**Code:**

```
  // React Hooks: Refs
  const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);

  // Send Verification Code
  const sendVerificationCode = (event: any) => {
    // Event: Cancels Event (Stops HTML Default Form Submit)
    event.preventDefault();

    // Event: Prevents Event Bubbling To Parent Elements
    event.stopPropagation();

    // const reference = <HTMLFormElement>formRef.current;


    console.log('WHY IS THE FORM VALID???');
    console.log(formRef.current.checkValidity());

    // Check Form Validity
    if (formRef.current.checkValidity() === true) {
      // Validate Form
      setValidated(true);

      // Redux: Send Verification Code Request
      dispatch(sendVerificationCodeRequest(email));
    }
    else {
      // Do Nothing (Form.Control.Feedback Will Appear)
      console.log('DO NOTHING');
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, the problem is that the ref could be `null` — and in fact, that's what you're initializing it to. That means `formRef.current` may be `null`. Which means `formRef.current.checkValidity()` needs a check for whether `formRef.current`  is `null`.

You can use `&&`:

```
if (formRef.current && formRef.current.checkValidity()) {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or the new [optional chaining operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining):

```
if (formRef.current?.checkValidity()) {
//                 ^
```

---

Side note: There's almost¹ never any reason for `=== true` or `=== false`, and certainly none above. `checkValidity` returns a boolean, so you *already* have a boolean to test with the `if`.

```
// Idiomatically:
if (x) {  // Is this true?
    // ...
}

if (!x) { // Is this false?
    // ...
}
```

---

¹ "almost" - The only time it really makes sense is if what you're testing may not be a boolean at all and you want the check to result in `false` if it isn't, which is a rare edge case.

Answer (score 0):

You must somehow ensure `formRef.current` is not `null`, because it could be. One way is to add this in the beginning of the callback:

```
if(!formRef.current) return
```

Also you could use the optional chaining operator, although in this case if `formRef.current` turns out to be `null`, the `DO NOTHING` part of code will be triggered

```
if(formRef.current?.checkValidity() === true)
```